# QueryDsl Generated Class throws Undefined Constructor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have added Query DSL in my spring boot project. And, Generated the QType Class by 'mvn compile'. Some of the generated class has compilation errors as
`The constructor QAddress(Class<Address>, PathMetadata, PathInits) is undefined` for the below constructors,

```
public QAddress(String variable) {
    this(Address.class, forVariable(variable), INITS);
}

public QAddress(Path<? extends Address> path) {
    this(path.getType(), path.getMetadata(), PathInits.getFor(path.getMetadata(), INITS));
}
```

Could you pls let me know what I'm missing in this?

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency> 
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId> 
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId> 
        <version>4.4.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

<plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including querydsl-core dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Compile after including this in your pom.xml.